# Creating a custom week counter in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to create a custom week counter but am having quite a lot of trouble and feel like I am going about it all wrong.  The method should take in a string date that is in yyyy-MM-dd format and return the week number.  The week counter started October 1, 2000.  The week starts Friday and ends Thursday.  The first 2 digits represents the years and the second 2 represent the week.  So this week would be 1143 (11 to represent the year and 43 to represent the weeks since Oct 1).

This is what I have gotten so far:

```
public static String get_week(String date){

    try{
        Calendar first_dt = Calendar.getInstance();
        first_dt.set(1999, 10, 01);
        long first_dt_milliseconds = first_dt.getTimeInMillis();

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date format_date = (Date)formatter.parse(date);

        SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM"); 
        SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

        long drop_dt_milliseconds = format_date.getTime() - first_dt_milliseconds;
        long drop_dt_years = drop_dt_milliseconds / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 365;

        Calendar year_ago = Calendar.getInstance();
        year_ago.set(Integer.parseInt(year.format(format_date))-1, 10, 01);

        long year_ago_milliseconds = year_ago.getTimeInMillis();

        long year_ago_diff = format_date.getTime() - year_ago_milliseconds;
        year_ago_diff = year_ago_diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 7;

        if (month.format(format_date).equals("10") || month.format(format_date).equals("11") || month.format(format_date).equals("12")){
            date = drop_dt_years+1+""+year_ago_diff;
        }
        else{
            date = year_ago_diff;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) because it's less confusing than Java's built-in date and time gear

EDIT - new code, rolled in ChssPly's suggestion and fixed a problem with the weeks between Oct 1 and Jan 1.  Also check out X-Zero's suggestion to create a custom Chronology in Joda-Time, might be an interesting approach.

```
import org.joda.time.DateMidnight;
import org.joda.time.Weeks;
import org.joda.time.Years;

public class Main {

    private String getWeek (DateMidnight dt2) {
        DateMidnight dt = new DateMidnight(2000,10,1);

        // First get the number of elapsed years, ChssPly76's way
        int yearz = Years.yearsBetween(dt, dt2).getYears();
        /*
         * We now need the number of weeks in the current year, which can be
         * calculated using the Weeks class.
         */
        int yearOffset = 1;
        // But if the new date is Oct 1 thru Dec 12 year must remain the same
        if (!dt2.isBefore (new DateMidnight(dt2.getYear(),10,1))) {
            yearOffset = 0;
        }

        int weekz = Weeks.weeksBetween(dt.withYear(dt2.getYear()-yearOffset), dt2).getWeeks();
        return(yearz + " " + weekz);
    }

    private void test (DateMidnight testDate) {
        System.out.println("For date " + testDate + " years/weeks = " + getWeek(testDate));
    }

    private void run() {
        test (new DateMidnight());
        test (new DateMidnight(2010,10,8));
        test (new DateMidnight(2010,9,30));
        test (new DateMidnight(2000,10,1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
For date 2011-07-26T00:00:00.000+02:00 years/weeks = 10 42
For date 2010-10-08T00:00:00.000+02:00 years/weeks = 10 1
For date 2010-09-30T00:00:00.000+02:00 years/weeks = 9 52
For date 2000-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 years/weeks = 0 0
```

Probably a slightly more sophisticated return object would be better....

Comment: The easier way would be to use Weeks (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html): int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(dt, dt2).getWeeks();

Comment: Along with this, he's likely to want to write his own chronology, as his starting week is also likely the start of his year.  If he does the necessary math to discover the start-of-year offset, finding the week-of-year becomes trivial.